# How to access the string index of a typescript type that mixes known and unknown string properties

Tags: typescript

I am trying to define and use a typescript type for objects that mix a couple of known properties of a certain type but can have an unknown number of additional properties of a different type. My issue is not the definition of such a type, as explained here e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430341/11150752. My trouble starts when actually accessing a variable of that type via index:

```js
    interface Foo {      
      length: number;
    }
    
    interface Bar {
        [key: string]: string ;
    }
    
    type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
    
    const foo : FooBar = {
      length: 1, // its ok defined in foo
      txt: "TXT", // string is ok
    };
    
    const l = foo.length  //no complaints here
    /* The next line causes 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression 
    // of type '"txt"' can't be used to index type 'FooBar'.
      Property 'txt' does not exist on type 'FooBar'.(7053)' */
    const txt = foo["txt"]  

    const txt2 = foo as Bar["txt"]  // It is accepted with an explicit type cast
```

Is there a way to avoid type casting in such a case?

Comment: Maybe you need a type guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### These are some simple solutions to your problem.

1. type guard

```
// const txt = foo["txt"]

let txt;
// ✅
if('txt' in foo) {
   txt = foo["txt"]  
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7L-gKH2QBsIQBzMACwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuI-Aeh+QDaAawgBPegGcwUUBQC6k6bK4BfbngJ9koSLEQoAQnCg5N-YsLGKZlBcik2KyLlrUEwogA6HjyALymxFpklDT0TGyc6shaAApQ6N5QHsgA5CFU1KnI6DDIHt5pEexQ2cASDOhgyHASEsAUIHCsZPlYqQ6yZSAAJhAAHvleKB1KlKkAdAAUAEwALACMCwCU0Zbi9mPy1srRWgKgff3hLCV2cCCiqgTuw2iYRiYBGFgAPsiPXAQI6CBSyDBMMh6C9Hv5AvgMmFkAsADQxfjAMAVdBCZB9GCgCA9bQgAGYaJgfpgegAIgAKgANcmk+FaTqUbQooQEFRfH5-aokcGA9ATKHUPB8EBYH7MTwkOA6CrUaAQTQAKmQ5NlDAGXKxyAQcEYEggFVSAFEyMxyNVgOKSMAEEiSKJkNRajU8akLqJsgUUOxtbqUANPFB9fVfsgzDk8p60qSiWBSdltSBUtV2MhfTiwFhDgMhoVUqDjJNovFEtAUknidkeuh9ZVqgNytUQ5G8w8C9MAOwABgArABmZbZBU8AhkaoxrjAGBTctgbr49DLCH5Yk8zACaPE0lyDRuDn-GMzVdYJ2PdcxrdC-gASXNFUQSE8kBxAHckYKLsh-VabWO7tqpEAA)

2. `keyof`

```
// const txt = foo["txt"]

// ✅
const txt = foo["txt" as keyof FooBar]
```

3. `keyof` + `typeof`

```
// const txt = foo["txt"]

// ✅
type KT = keyof typeof foo;
const txt = foo["txt" as KT]
```

Comment: I had success with the second suggestion. I would have liked the type guard solution better but it seems to work only with explicit keys. When I use a string variable instead of "txt" I still get the old error. So something like if (idx in foo) txt = foo[idx] does not seem to work. Is that expected?

Comment: ja, I see now that the type guard cannot possibly know what the variable would be at runtime so no clear type can be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyType = {
    knownProp1: string;
    knownProp2: number;
    // Other known properties
    [key: string]: unknown;
};

// Access the type of a string index
type StringIndexType<T> = T extends { [key: string]: infer U } ? U : never;

// Example usage
type KnownProp1Type = StringIndexType<MyType['knownProp1']>;
```