# Typing the rest parameter of destructured function parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I type the rest parameters in a function in TypeScript?

```
type Params = {
  stringVar: string;
  boolVar: boolean;
  [key: string]: string;
};

const foo = ({ stringVar, boolVar, ...rest }: Params) => {
   // Do something that requires the values of rest to be string
}

foo({
  stringVar: 'Test',
  boolVar: true,
  name1: 'Deno',
  name2: 'Doe',
});
```

I always get the error:

```
Property 'boolVar' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

If I change my type to:

```
type Params = {
  stringVar: string;
  boolVar: boolean;
  [key: string]: string | boolean;
};
```

it "works", but all the values in `rest` are string. How can I tell TypeScript that these are separate types?

I would expect TypeScript to regard the specified variables as independent variables and only the rest is typed via `{[key: string]: string;}`. But this does not seem to be the case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem isn't in the destructuring, it's combining the index signature with specific properties: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63430129/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you very much! I already split them into different types, but I used an intersection type instead of a union. This fixes the problem. If you add this information as a reply, I will gladly accept it.