# How to type object with index signature and dynamic variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, index-signature

I am new to TypeScript, and have tried various ways to type this, but running into problems with index signatures. What should the interface look like?

```
interface MyConfig {
...
}

// someVar can be any string
let someVar = "dynamicKey";

// the structure of the object cannot change
const config: MyConfig = {
  myObj: {
    [someVar]: {
      firstProp: 'some text',
      secondProp: 'some text',
    },
    thirdProp: 'some text',
  },
};
```

Comment: `[someVar]:` is the same as `SomeKey:`. So type it as `SomeKey: {firstProp: string, secondProp: string}`

Comment: so you are saying what should my interface look like?

Comment: is `someVar` a dynamic string?

Comment: @zerkms cannot use your suggestion, as someVar is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact value or values for `someVar` variable, you can have a strict interface like:

```
interface MyConfig {
    myObj: {
        SomeKey: {
            firstProp: string
            secondProp: string
        },
        thirdProp: string
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
const someVar = "SomeKey";

const config: MyConfig = {
    myObj: {
        [someVar]: {
            firstProp: 'some text',
            secondProp: 'some text',
        },
        thirdProp: 'some text',
    },
};
```

But if you wish that `someVar` would be dynamic, it's a bit tricky. For that I would recommend you moving the dynamic part to a separate block, so you could use:

```
interface MyConfig {
    myObj: {
        dynamic: {
            [key: string]: {
                firstProp: string
                secondProp: string
            }
        },
        thirdProp: string
    }
}

const someVar = "SomeKey";
const config: MyConfig = {
    myObj: {
        dynamic: {
            [someVar]: {
                firstProp: 'some text',
                secondProp: 'some text',
            },
        },
        thirdProp: 'some text',
    },
};
```

And finally, if you have dynamic `someVar` and can't change the data structure. you can use following:

```
interface MyConfig {
    myObj: ({
        [key: string]: {
            firstProp: string
            secondProp: string
        } | string
    } & {
        thirdProp: string
    })
}
const someVar: string = "SomeKey";

const config: MyConfig = {
    myObj: {
        [someVar]: {
            firstProp: 'some text',
            secondProp: 'some text',
        },
        thirdProp: 'some text',
    },
};

// String
console.log(config.myObj.thirdProp.trim())

// Error, union string | object
console.log(config.myObj.abc.firstProp)

if (typeof config.myObj.abc === 'object') {
    // string
    console.log(config.myObj.thirdProp.trim())
    // string
    console.log(config.myObj.abc.firstProp.trim())
}
```

In this example, we use a typescript index signature + we specify known properties. You can also notice a strange thing - the index signature has union `object | string`. This is because of typescript limitation:

> As soon as you have a string index signature, all explicit members must also conform to that index signature. This is to provide safety so that any string access gives the same result.

Reference: [How to combine declared interface properties with custom Index Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592546/how-to-combine-declared-interface-properties-with-custom-index-signature)

Comment: when i use your last answer, the tsc compiler says: 

Type '{ SomeKey: { firstProp: string; secondProp: string; }; thirdProp: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ dynamic: { [key: string]: { firstProp: string; secondProp: string; }; }; thirdProp: string; }'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[someVar]' does not exist in type '{ dynamic: { [key: string]: { firstProp: string; secondProp: string; }; }; thirdProp: string; }'.ts(2322)

The expected type comes from property 'myObj' which is declared here on type 'MyConfig'

Comment: If you are using the last example, you will need to change how you store data (I updated the last example). As you can see I wrapped `[someVar]: {}` block to `dynamic` for typing convenience.

Comment: two problems: 
1. option does not work, as someVar is dynamic
2. option does not work, because i cannot change the structure of the object.

Comment: Added a third example. It's not the best, but it should work.

Comment: i see, it's working. i will mark it as the correct answer. Can you explain to me:
```
[key: string]: {
            firstProp: string
            secondProp: string
        } | string
```
why is `| string` needed?

Comment: Added an explanation after the last example.

Comment: thanks for the update. The problem I have, I do not know the name of the object key, so I need to access the property with the variable : 

`if (typeof config.myObj[someVar] === 'object')`

but this will throw TS errors and not give me autocomplete. Here a codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-morning-38y19?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Assign to variable and then do the checking:

```
const myvar = config.myObj[someVar]

if (typeof myvar === "object") {
  console.log(myvar.firstProp.trim());
}
```