# Create Dynamic Record Type in TypeScript based on Key value

Tags: typescript

Currently I do have below Interface on my application. Is it possible to create record type `PropA` based on key value.
e.g : if I pass `"apple"` as record key it will expect `IApple` interface on value else it will expect `IModel`.

```
interface Itest {
  propsA: Record<string,IModel>
}
```

Comment: You have to have a mapping of names to types somewhere in your code `type Map = { apple: IApple; model: IModel }`.  Do you have that?

Comment: I can add that mapping, can you please elaborate how I can use this mapping?

Comment: When you say "pass "apple" as record key" what do you mean?  Do you mean that you want this to be generic, like `Itest<"apple">` has `propsA: Record<string, IApple>`?  Or do you mean that the `propsA` itself is an object like `{ apple: IApple; model: IModel }`?  In the second case you do not need a `Record` type at all.  It would just be `interface Itest { propsA: Map }` with the `Map` like in the previous comment.

Comment: propsA: Record<string,IModel> -> if {string} value is "apple" IModel should be type of IApple else IModel.

Comment: Is `IApple` a subtype of `IModel` or totally different?  It's tough if they are different.  Easy if it's a subtype.

Comment: Both are different, Can up send me the code for subtype, let me see if can change to subtype.

Comment: Re: if they are different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592546/how-to-combine-declared-interface-properties-with-custom-index-signature

Answer (score 0):

You want a type for an object where all `string` keys have a value of type `IModel` **except** for the key `"apple"` which has a value `IApple`.

If `IApple` is a subtype of `IModel` then this is very simple.  `Record<string, IModel>` declares that all properties must be `IModel`.  We combine that with `& {apple?: IApple}` which says that the property `apple` must also be `IApple`.  The `?` means that `apple` is optional.

```
interface Itest {
  propsA: Record<string, IModel> & {apple?: IApple}
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/PmLzAw)

If `IApple` and `IModel` are two unrelated types then this becomes trickier because the `Record<string, IModel>` applies to every `string` including `apple` and we get an error "Property 'apple' is incompatible with index signature."  We need to say that the value is `IModel` for every key except `apple`.