# Nested recursive Type Hinting in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, types, eslint

I'm not entirely sure if I'm calling this right so I'll explain.

I'm creating React app using TypeScript, in order to make my life simpler I want to store all routings paths as constants separately, I also want to have TypeScript like auto-completion in VS Code. So I have this king of structure:

```
type GlobalRoutingT = 'user' | 'listing';

type RoutingVariants = {
  list: string,
  add: string,
  get: string,
  [key: string]: RoutingVariants | string,
};

type RouterT = Record<GlobalRoutingT, RoutingVariants>;

export const Routes: RouterT = {
  user: {
    list: '/user',
    add: '/user/add',
    get: '/user/:id',
    invoices: {
      list: '/user/invoices',
      add: '/user/invoices/add',
      get: '/user/invoices/:id',
    }
  },
  listing: {
    list: '/listing',
    add: '/listing/add',
    get: '/listing/:id',
  },
};
```

It works all great I can use it like this at the moment

```
<Route path={Routes.user.invoices.get} exact >
  <GetInvoice />
</Route>
```

But inside VS Code I get error:

> Property 'get' does not exist on type 'string | RoutingVariants'. Property 'get' does not exist on type 'string'.

and
Routes.user.invoices.**get** part is highlighted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that `[key: string]: RoutingVariants | string` says that _any_ property of `RoutingVariants` can have `string` as type, so `Routes.user.invoices` can technically be a string. I'm not sure how to work around that, yet.

Comment: @Cerbrus Sounds about right, but it's frustrating and I dont understand if it's eslint problem or I'm just bad at TypeScript.

Comment: have you had a look at my answer? I think that's the closest to what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want isn't exactly possible:
[How to combine known interface properties with a custom index signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592546/how-to-combine-known-interface-properties-with-a-custom-index-signature)

You can't combine an index signature with named keys on the same interface / type.

As a workaround, you *could* use a "child" property, like this:

```
type GlobalRoutingT = 'user' | 'listing';

type RoutingVariants = {
    list: string,
    add: string,
    get: string,
    child?: Record<string, RoutingVariants>
};

type RouterT = Record<GlobalRoutingT, RoutingVariants>;

export const Routes: RouterT = {
    user: {
        list: '/user',
        add: '/user/add',
        get: '/user/:id',
        child: {
            invoices: {
                list: '/user/invoices',
                add: '/user/invoices/add',
                get: '/user/invoices/:id'
            }
        }
    },
    listing: {
        list: '/listing',
        add: '/listing/add',
        get: '/listing/:id'
    }
};

const a = Routes.user.child?.invoices.get;
```

Notice how I have to use `?.` to access the child, as it's optional on the type definition.

You could replace `child` with something shorter, a single letter, `$` or `_`...

Comment: Sorry for delay, it looks like the most strait forward way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the type cast, try this:

```
<Route path={(Routes.user.invoices as RoutingVariants).get} exact >
  <GetInvoice />
</Route>
```

Comment: Works, but if nesting continues, this is gonna stack pretty quickly ;'(